# If $L^1$ is the space of lebesgue-integrable functions on $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$, does it matter whether or not $\mu$ is complete?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $L_1(\mu)$ be the space of Lebesgue-integrable functions on $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$. That is, $L^1$ is the set of equivalence classes of the relation $f \sim g \iff f = g\ \mu-$a.e., equipped with the metric $d(f, g) = \int |f - g|\ d\mu$.

Is it important whether or not $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ is a complete measure space? What are some properties of $L^1$ that hold only if $\mu$ is complete?

Comment: Measures are countably additive.  Much of the basic theory relies on that.

Comment: @herbsteinberg could you please expand on this? I'm not sure how that relates.

Comment: $\mu$ not Complete means what to you?  The completeness of $L_1$ is defined in terms of completeness of a normed vector space.  Completeness of the measure space means it is a $\sigma-field$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg completeness in the sense that $\mathcal{F}$ contains all of the null sets. I'm not asking about completeness of $L^1$ here.

Comment: @herbsteinberg Given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ it is possible to have $B \in \mathcal{F}, \mu(B)=0$ and $A \subseteq B$ but $A \notin \mathcal F$.( For example, it is easy to argue that the Cantor set contains subsets which are NOT Borel.) This phenomena can somehow create small issues around $\mu$-almost everywhere convergence. A measure is called complete if $\mu(B)=0$ and $A \subseteq B$ implies that $A \in \mathcal F$. Note that this actually a property of $\mu$ AND $\mathcal F$. It is easy to argue that given a measure space $(X, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$

Comment: There exists an unique minimal completion $(X, \mathcal{F}_0, \mu_0)$, where any element $A \in  \mathcal{F}_0$ can be written as $A=B \cup C$ with $B \in \mathcal{F}$ and $C$ a subset of a null set, and of course $\mu_0(A)=\mu(B)$... Thus assuming that a measure is complete is typically just a convention that $\mathcal{F}$ is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it sometimes depends.

For example, the Dominated Convergence Theorem is saying that if $f_n$ is dominated by $g$ and converges pointwise to $f$ then $f$ is integrable and
$$
\lim_n \int |f_n-f| d \mu =0
$$

When $\mu$ is complete, it is enough to assume that $f_n$ is dominated by $g$ and converges pointwise **$\mu$-almost everywhere** to $f$, but this is not true in general.

For a counterexample, pick a subset $E \subset X$ which is a subset of a null set but no measurable and observe that $f_n=0$ converges to $f=1_{E}$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

[Side note I actually run into this issue once in a paper, luckly I could assume that my measure ws complete.]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we say that $f_n \to 1_{E}$ $\mu$-a.e.? If $f_n = 0$, then the set $\{x : f_n(x) \not\to 1_{E}\}$ is $E$, and since $E$ is not measurable then it's not true that $\mu(E) = 0$. Is that right? I could be misunderstanding the definitions.

Comment: @TheProofIsTrivium $E$ is a subset of a set $B$ with $\mu(B)=0$. And $f_n(x) \to 1_{E}(x)$ for all $x \notin B$, thus $\mu$ almost everywhere. Note that convergence a.e. means that there exists a measurable $B \subseteq X$ set of measure $0$ such that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x \in X \backslash B$ and not as the set $\{ x : f_n(x) \to f(x) \}$ having zero measure. The first definition is much easier to use, and of course for complete measures they are equivalent, but for non-complete measures you are using the wrong definition.

Comment: Thanks, the problem specifically is that if $\mu$ is not complete, the point-wise limit $f$ of the $f_n$ may not be measurable. Is that right? Then this would be problematic for all the limit theorems, not just the dominated convergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If you have a single measurable function (or countably many measurable functions) then anything you define from them is again measurable.  So completeness is not needed.

(2) But if you have uncountably many, that no longer works.  For example, in probability theory, a "stochastic process" may be a collection $(f_t)_{t \ge 0}$ of random variables indexed by the nonnegative reals.  And you may want some uncountable constructions still to yield something measurable.  That is where completeness is important.  Example:
$$
T(x) = \inf\{t \; : \; |f_t(x)| \ge 1\}
$$
We may want $T$ to be measurable.  In some cases, we can provide natural conditions on the process $(f_t)$ that will insure this when the measure is complete.

(3)  If $E \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ is a Borel set, then the projection onto the $x$-axis is
$$
p(E) = \{x \in \mathbb R\;:\;\exists y, (x,y \in E\} .
$$
If $E$ is Borel in $\mathbb R^2$, then $p(E)$ need not be a Borel set in $\mathbb R$.  But in fact $p(E)$ is measurable with respect to any complete Borel measure on $\mathbb R$.